# Does System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter not exist in windows 8 metro style app development?

Tags: windows, windows-runtime

I'm trying to display RAM used on a windows 8 metro style app (using VS 2012).

I'm trying to use the following code:

```
PerformanceCounter ramCounter;
```

I get an error saying VS 2012 can't find PerformanceCounter.

It does not seem to exist in System.Diagnositcs. How can I display RAM or CPU on a win 8 style app?

Answer (score 1):

It does not show up in the Object Browser search results, hence - it is not supported in WinRT apps.

Sometimes you can also tell for specific APIs by the "**Applies to**: desktop apps/Metro style apps" string in the documentation like [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162913%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162913%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I think that is only available if the API is a Windows API.

Most .NET APIs are not Windows APIs and if they are not available in WinRT Apps - they are not documented on the Windows documentation site. MSDN does not include these "**Applies to**" strings.